# Obtain same results when evaluating a Spark SQL query twice with LIMIT

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have recently started using pyspark and I encountered some behavior that I am trying to better understand, and avoid.

Consider the following code:

```
query1 = "SELECT * FROM A where X >= 1000000 and X < 1001000 LIMIT 50"
s1 = spark.sql(query1)
X_vals = s1.select('X').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

query2 = "SELECT * FROM B" + " where Y in " + '('  + ','.join([str(x) for x in X_vals]) + ')'
s2 = spark.sql(query2)

s1.write.mode('overwrite').option("header", True).option("sep",'\t').csv('test/A.csv')
s2.write.mode('overwrite').option("header", True).option("sep",'\t').csv('test/B.csv')
```

From `A`, I obtain a sample of 50 records from a range, and store the values of `X` in `X_vals`. I then take the same records (where `Y` in `X_vals`) from table `B`.

Later, I write both tables to `csv` files. In the resulting `csv` files, the `X`'s in `A` do not match the `Y`'s in `B` anymore.

I think this is explainable behavior and is caused by lazy evaluation; the records selected in the `collect()` statement are not the same records as the ones in the `.csv` statement. However my understanding of Spark is not yet good enough to explain exactly why this happens.

So; why does this happen, and is there a way to force the query to return the same results twice (without joining the tables)?

Thanks,

Florian

Comment: How about using `order by` to force query1 to a specific order?

Comment: @Bala, I guess `ORDER BY could` work indeed, although I am not sure. My intuitive explanation for this behavior is that the above is stochastic because it depends on which executor is finished first. In the case of `order by` would it first collect 20 records and then order, or first order all the records and then collect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the implementation of `LIMIT` . It implemented by shuffling records to a single partition (you can find detailed explanation in the excellent answer to [Towards limiting the big RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38710018/8371915)).

At the same time, Spark follows SQL standard rules - if there is no explicit order, then optimizer can choose arbitrary records.

```
val df = spark.range(1000)

df.where($"id".between(100, 200)).limit(10).explain
== Physical Plan ==
CollectLimit 10
+- *LocalLimit 10
   +- *Filter ((id#16L >= 100) && (id#16L <= 200))
      +- *Range (0, 1000, step=1, splits=4)
```

To get deterministic (somewhat, AFAIK ties are resolved nondeterministically) order use `orderBy` clause, to convert `CollectLimit` into `TakeOrderedAndProject`:

```
df.where($"id".between(100, 200)).orderBy("id").limit(10).explain
== Physical Plan ==
TakeOrderedAndProject(limit=10, orderBy=[id#16L ASC NULLS FIRST], output=[id#16L])
+- *Filter ((id#16L >= 100) && (id#16L <= 200))
   +- *Range (0, 1000, step=1, splits=4)
```