# Load a random sample of csv file s3 pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, pyspark

I'm trying load a random sample of a total of 100mill row data in s3. 
Is there an easy way to load a random sample from s3 in to pyspark dataframe directly?

In pandas this would like this
    `df = pandas.read_csv(filename, skiprows=skiplines)`

Is there an equivalent in pyspark i could use?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806084/sampling-a-large-distributed-data-set-using-pyspark-spark/24809595

Answer (score 2):

I believe that spark's [`DataFrameReader.csv`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv) is [lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38027877/spark-transformation-why-its-lazy-and-what-is-the-advantage) by default <sup>[citation needed]</sup>.

So, you should be able to read the csv and use [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sample`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sample):

```python
frac = 0.01 # get approximately 1%
df = spark.read.csv(filename)
sample = df.sample(withReplacement=False, fraction=frac)
```

But nothing actually executes until you apply a transformation.

Comment: So to understand you correctly: The full dataset in s3 is NOT loaded in to memory before sampling? It only loads the randomly selected (1% in this case) in to memory?

Comment: TBH, I can't say for sure but I _believe_ this is the case. Do you have a limitation? Is it something you can test to see if it works for your case?